# Can you enable chrome.storage and chrome.fileSystem for normal localhost testing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome App and it's irritating using the suggested workflow of manually refreshing the app every time I make a change. I'd like to use a normal localhost server workflow but I need access to chrome.storage and chrome.fileSystem. Is there a way to enable these features outside of the extensions sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to enable these features outside of the extensions sandbox?

### No.

Not directly, anyway.

You could *conceivably* make a proxy extension/app that will execute privileged commands for you using [`"externally_connectable"` messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

But that will not help you in development - you'll need to proxy all API calls in a complicated way. It would probably also fail for APIs that require user gestures.

---

You should instead look into programmatically reloading your app by some external command. This is possible - an extension using [`management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) and a native "proxy" module using WebSockets or [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) can allow you to refresh your app by any event in the system.

It's the approach taken by [GhostText](https://github.com/Cacodaimon/GhostText-for-SublimeText), for instance.